# Find out who is hosting a website given an ip address

Tags: web-hosting

Say I have an URL or an IP for a website.

Is there a way to tell who is hosting that site? Rackspace, Azure, Amazon etc?

Comment: Why are you trying to determine what hosting provider is being used and why does it matter?

Comment: @Ramhound Probably he wants to find a good hosting provider, and he wants to check famous sites to find out good ones.

Comment: @Ramhound  You ask "Why are you trying to determine what hosting provider is being used and why does it matter?" One could likewise ask   why does your question matter.  If you want to vote to close then don't threaten to do it, just do it. You haven't stated what rule you think his question is in breach of.  Or why how he answers that question will determine whether you will vote to close it or not. Your threat to him might be a bit more fair if you tell him what you deem acceptable.

Comment: @Ramhound what does it matter, obviously there is a reason for the question since I am asking it. Do I need to justify asking a question that other people cannot find useful?

Comment: @lox - I wanted to better understand the question you were asking.  In order to do that I need more information.  I also wanted to make sure your question didn't fit better on another stack exchange website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This site will tell you](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/#).

Generally, the theory of this is that the DNS name of the website resolves to an IP.

That IP will be one of a bank of addresses used by a webhost.

Alternatively, you can view the full whois information which will normally contain a record for the webmaster.  Failing that, you can lookup the DNS records of a website and see who the nameservers are registered to or similar.

Comment: I checked this on some websites, it didn't work for most of them (whereas I could see their full info on Who.Is)

Comment: Interesting... I've checked for my work domain, personal email domain, my 2 previous employers domains and they all gave the correct different results.

Comment: That is one ugly site. The site http://www.iptools.biz/ has been around for years and is good for checking the regional internet registrars in its whois.

Comment: IT is indeed ugly, but seems to work for the most part.  I used to recommend network-tools.com, but in my line of work, I often deal with non-technicals so try to find the simplest solutions available

Answer (score 6):

If you only have the IP address, you can do some investigation as follows. I will use I will use 23.226.227.64 (gwhois.org) and my suite of tools at GWhois.org for the examples.

1. Do a Whois lookup for the IP address: https://gwhois.org/23.226.227.64

   We can see that this IP address is registered to Ramnode.

   [image: screenshot]

   Also, on the whois details we may find the company's website, for example.

   [image: screenshot]
2. Do a Reverse DNS lookup for the IP address: https://gwhois.org/rdns/23.226.227.64

   The IP address has a PTR (pointer) record for gwhois.org.

   [image: screenshot]
3. If a domain name is found in the Reverse DNS lookup, then you can do a Whois lookup for the domain name itself: https://gwhois.org/gwhois.org

   [image]

So in the very least, you can find out who the IP address is registered to and reach out to that company for more information. If the IP address has a PTR record, then you can do also Whois lookup for that domain and reach out to the the owner for more info as well.